# @ResponseStatus annotation: maps exceptions to a specified status code

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404

I stumbled across Craig Walls [Manning Spring4 in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/spring-in-action-fourth-edition).

Consider the snippet:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/students/{studentId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String students(Model model,
                           @PathVariable("studentId") long studentId) {


        List<Student> students = studentRepository.findOne(studentId); 

        Student student = null;
        for (Spittle getStudent : students) {
            student = getStudent;
        }
        if (student == null) {
            throw new StudentNotFoundException();
        }

        model.addAttribute("studentList", students); 

        return "students";
}
```

At one point, the author puts forward,

> If the above method is called on to handle a request, and the given ***ID***
>   comes up ***empty***, the ***StudentNotFoundException*** will ***by default*** result in
>   a response with a ***500(Internal Server Error) status code***. In fact, in
>   the event of ***any exception*** that isn't ***otherwise mapped***, the ***response***
>   will ***always*** have a ***500  status code***. But you can change that by mapping
>   StudentNotFoundException otherwise.
>
> When ***StudentNotFoundException*** is thrown, it's a situation where
>   a ***requested resource isn't found***. The ***HTTP status code of
>   404*** is precisely the ***appropriate response status code*** when a
>   ***resource isn't found***. So let's use ***@ResponseStatus to map StudentNotFoundException to Http status code 404***.

But I see when i type the ***URL*** in my browser, and this is before any mapping,

> http://localhost:8080/web/students/

[image]

it doesn't results in ***Http Status code of 500*** as suggested by author. In fact, it is ***by default 404***. So there is no need to map it as the author does in the next lines of code.

Edit:

The above code works fine when I need to retrieve a student passing student as the path variable,

[image]

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason = "Student Not Found")
public class StudentNotFoundException
    extends RuntimeException {

}
```

Is the author wrong or am I missing something on my end?

Comment: @Jens: Maybe you have the impression that the project is not working fine when I pass id as the path variable. Again edited and see the screenshot

Comment: Ok that variable is mendatory. I think you have to change your request mapping to `@RequestMapping(value = {"/students/", "/students/{studentId}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)`. In the other case the request will not be mapped to your controller method.

Comment: @Jens: But that will be of no use to me.

Comment: Why not? in case you have no id your controller method is not called.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the controller method is never called. The correct test would be

```
http://localhost:8080/web/students/1234
```

when there is no student with id 1234.

If you want to have code executed for   `http://localhost:8080/web/students` you'll need to add another method with mapping `@RequestMapping(value = "/students", method = RequestMethod.GET)`

Comment: I checked it passing 1234 as the path variable. It's 404 as usual.

Comment: What do you mean by mapping? You have this in your exception definition: `@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason = "Student Not Found")` - this is mapping